# Is continuous surjective image of $R_0$ space $R_0$?

Tags: general-topology

Let $(X, \mathcal{T}_X)$ be a topological $R_0$ space, i.e. for any $U \in \mathcal{T}_X$ we have $U = \bigcup_{x \in U} \overline{\{x\}}(X)$. Let $(Y, \mathcal{T}_Y)$ be a space, and $f: X \to Y$ be continuous and surjective. Is $f[X] = Y$ an $R_0$ space?

Wikipedia lists other characterizations for [$R_0$ spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T1_space).

Comment: What does $\overline{\{x\}}(X)$ mean?

Comment: Can you clarify the title a little bit?

Comment: Closure in $X$.

Comment: How do you want to clarify it? Do you mean subscript zeros?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Counterexample: Let $Y$ be any non-$R_0$ space, let $X$ be the discrete space with the same underlying point-set, and let $f\colon X \to Y$ be the identity function.

Comment: Can't get simpler than that!

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a counter-example after asking the question. Let

- $X = \{0\} \cup \{1/n : n \in \mathbb{N}^{> 0}\}$,
- $\mathcal{T}_X$ is the subspace topology of $X$ in $\mathbb{R}$,
- $Y = \mathbb{N}$,
- $\mathcal{T}_Y = \{\emptyset, \mathbb{N}\} \cup \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}^{\geq 2}) \cup \{U \subset \mathbb{N} : 1 \in U, 0 \not\in U, |\mathbb{N} \setminus U| < \infty\}$, where $\mathcal{P}$ stands for set of subsets.
- $f: X \to Y$ is such that $f(1/n) = n$ and $f(0) = 0$ for each $n \in \mathbb{N}^{>0}$.

The topology $\mathcal{T}_Y$ here has previously been used for counter-examples in other topics [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/416575/32487) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4392055/51161). Now:

- $X$ is $R_0$, because $\mathbb{R}$ is $R_0$, and a subspace of $R_0$ space is $R_0$.
- $Y$ is not $R_0$, since $0$ and $2$ are topologically distinguishable ($\{2\} \in \mathcal{T}_Y(2)$, but $\{2\} \not \in \mathcal{T}_Y(0)$), but the only neighborhood of $0$ is $\mathbb{N}$ which contains $2$.

We still need to show $f$ continuous. Suppose $V \in \mathcal{T}_Y$. If $0 \in V$, then $f^{-1}(V) = f^{-1}(\mathbb{N}) = X \in \mathcal{T}_X$. If $0 \not\in V$, then $f^{-1}(V) \in \mathcal{T}_X$, because it is a subset of $\{1/n : n \in \mathbb{N}^{> 0}\}$ whose every subset is open. Therefore $f$ is continuous.

EDIT: a much simplified concrete counter-example following the accepted answer:

- $X = \{0, 1\}$,
- $\mathcal{T}_X = \{\emptyset, \{0\}, \{1\}, X\}$
- $Y = X$,
- $\mathcal{T}_Y = \{\emptyset, \{0\}, Y\}$,
- $f : X \to Y$ such that $f(x) = x$.

Then $\mathcal{T}_X$ is the discrete topology, and so it is $R_0$, and  $f$ is continuous. On the other hand, $\mathcal{T}_Y$ is not $R_0$, since $0$ and $1$ are topologically distinguishable, but the only neighborhood of $1$ is $Y$ which contains $0$.